# php pull from two columns and two likes at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure the best way to ask this and I am sorry if I paste anything that is incorrectly or not as I should. I'm not trying to be a pain on purpose, its just that I have gotten complaints before off this from admins.. Please excuse my english.

Anywho what I am looking to do is pull from two columns, and have it operate with two likes at the same time, I can figure out how to put this in a format.

When I use this code below I get a error.. how I put this into one line?

```
Put this into one line  -
```

> WHERE productnumber LIKE %colname% 
>   WHERE option1 LIKE %colname2%

I would like it to look something like this

> WHERE productnumber AND option1 LIKE %colname%, %colname2%

In other words

producnumber only equals - colname

option1 only equals - colname2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic answer:

```
WHERE productnumber LIKE '%colname%' AND option1 LIKE '%colname2%'
```

We don't know what 'colname' and 'colname2' are exactly, so its harder to state. If you aren't using wild-cards, then you could just use fixed matching:

```
SELECT something FROM tablename 
WHERE tablename.productnumber = 'colname' 
AND tablename.option1 = 'colname2'
```

Hard to say exactly, unless you post code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful!! That worked.. thats the one... I knew it something easy that I was missing with the And..

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE productnumber LIKE '%colname%' AND option1 LIKE '%colname2%'
```

assuming `colname` and `colname2` are strings / user input.